# OptiFine mod installed and launching correctly but not changing any textures

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

I'm explaining this through images. I installed last version of OptiFine:
[image]

I click "Play" and then go to "Video Settings"

[image]

I change  "Animations" like this:

[image]

So as far as i know, some textures should have been changed. But water etc still remains in their "default" mode:

[image]

So, question would be: what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing nothing, really. These options gives you the ability to disable certain particles and animated textures - it doesn't add anything.

These only affects blocks:

- `Water Animated` (Flowing water)
- `Lava Animated` (Flowing lava)
- `Fire Animated` (Fire created with a fire charge or flint and steel)
- `Portal Animated` (Nether portal blocks)
- `Terrain Animated` & `Textures Animated` (Affects sea lanterns, among other animated textures)

These only affects particles:

- `Redstone Animated` (Particles that emits from active redstone)
- `Explosion Animated` (Explosions from TNT/creepers)
- `Flame Animated` (Flame particles from torches)
- `Smoke Animated` (Smoke from torches)
- `Void Particles` (Particles that appears around y:0)
- `Water Particles` (Splashes from entities jumping/swimming in water)
- `Rain Splash` (Splashes that appears during rain)
- `Portal Particles` (Particles from Nether portals)
- `Potion Particles` (Colored particles that emits from an entity with a potion effect)
- `Dripping Water/Lava` (Water/lava droplets from a block that has water/lava on top of it)
- `Firework Particles` (Particles from firework rockets)

Comment: yeah but i saw a video where the youtuber installed OptiFine and then his minecraft had transparent water (not blue as in default mode), grass been moved by the wind, etc.

Comment: That's a shader. Optifine is one of the mods you can use to load shaders, but you still have to have the shader, too.